# Nested loops in ansible while creating k8s secrets

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create k8s secrets with the storing username and secret in results module of ansible but i created one loop for the name and namespace section and i am trying to create one more loop from the json results output

**variables:**

```yaml
project_namespaces:
  - projectName: helm
    Namespaces: 
      - default
      - core
```

**robot_result.results**

```json
    "robot_result.results | json_query('[].json')": [
        {
            "creation_time": "2022-03-21T10:29:18.331Z",
            "expires_at": -1,
            "id": 75,
            "username": "robot@helm-robot",
            "secret": "YzDDEtJcqYoBL2soZHfTqZxvhIfGKURT"
        },
        {
            "creation_time": "2022-03-21T10:29:22.129Z",
            "expires_at": -1,
            "id": 76,
            "username": "robot@proxy-robot",
            "secret": "7imXCVAGHV91AkeN7LAhWxQHabmYDRmg"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Tasks:**

```yaml
- name: Create secrets
  k8s: 
    state: present
    definition:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Secret
      metadata:
        name: "{{ item.0.projectName }}"
        namespace: "{{ item.1 }}"
      stringData:
        password: "{{ project.secret }}"
        username: "{{ project.name }}"
      type: Opaque
  vars:
    project: "{{ robot_result.results | json_query('[*].json') | first }}"  
  loop: "{{ project_namespaces | subelements('Namespaces') }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.0.projectName }}"
```

when i tried to execute this tasks, it's creating the secrets but it's creating every secret with the same name and secret, because i am using `project: "{{ robot_result.results | json_query('[*].json') | first }}"`  it's printing only first value of the results every time.

I am not much aware of this ansible to create two loops in this tasks. can anyone please help me on this to achieve this..i am posting the results and output of the robot account.

I am getting the output like

```yaml
name: "helm" , namespace: "default", username: "robot@helm-robot", secret: "YzDDEtJcqYoBL2soZHfTqZxvhIfGKURT"
name: "helm" , namespace: "core", username: "robot@helm-robot", secret: "YzDDEtJcqYoBL2soZHfTqZxvhIfGKURT"
```

but i am looking the output should be

```
name: "helm" , namespace: "default", username: "robot@helm-robot", secret: "YzDDEtJcqYoBL2soZHfTqZxvhIfGKURT"
name: "helm" , namespace: "core", username: "robot@proxy-robot", secret: "7imXCVAGHV91AkeN7LAhWxQHabmYDRmg"
```

I was getting error like

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'secret'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ubuntu/konvoy/ansible/roles/harbor/tasks/main.yml': line 47, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Create secrets\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Thanks in advance.

**robot_result:**

```
ok: [harbor_stg1_dkp1] => {
    "robot_result": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "content_type": "application/json",
                "cookies": {
                    "sid": "557b377ba2bbe3f054d68bd56b0e10ef"
                },
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "attributes": null,
                        "body": {
                            "description": "pull artifacts for helm",
                            "disable": true,
                            "duration": -1,
                            "level": "system",
                            "name": "helm-robot",
                            "permissions": [
                                {
                                    "access": [
                                        {
                                            "action": "pull",
                                            "resource": "repository"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "kind": "project",
                                    "namespace": "helm"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "body_format": "json",
                        "headers": {
                            "Accept": "application/json",
                            "Authorization": "Basic ",
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        },
                        "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
                        "status_code": [
                            201
                        ],
                        "timeout": 30,
                        "unix_socket": null,
                        "validate_certs": false
                    }
                },
                "item": {
                    "name": "helm-robot",
                    "projectName": "helm"
                },
                "json": {
                    "creation_time": "2022-03-21T10:05:49.248Z",
                    "expires_at": -1,
                    "id": 67,
                    "name": "robot@helm-robot",
                    "secret": "Q8mjthgRJFmscjfmqW1QzXEyKjmLEPQm"
                },
                "x_envoy_upstream_service_time": "18",
                "x_request_id": "496faaa6-bdc4-4e83-890a-2c577576f16b"
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "content_type": "application/json",
                "cookies": {
                    "sid": "6275d7bfe74e71db0a3947f4beb1e159"
                },
                "cookies_string": "sid=6275d7bfe74e71db0a3947f4beb1e159",
                "date": "Mon, 21 Mar 2022 10:05:56 GMT",
                "elapsed": 1,
                "failed": false,
                "failed_when_result": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "attributes": null,
                        "body": {
                            "description": "pull artifacts for proxy",
                            "disable": true,
                            "duration": -1,
                            "level": "system",
                            "name": "proxy-robot",
                            "permissions": [
                                {
                                    "access": [
                                        {
                                            "action": "pull",
                                            "resource": "repository"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "kind": "project",
                                    "namespace": "proxy"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "body_format": "json",
                        "group": null,
                        "headers": {
                            "Accept": "application/json",
                            "Authorization": "Basic ",
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        },
                        "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
                        "method": "POST"
                        ],
                        "timeout": 30,
                        "unix_socket": null,
                        "validate_certs": false
                    }
                },
                "item": {
                    "name": "proxy-robot",
                    "projectName": "proxy"
                },
                "json": {
                    "creation_time": "2022-03-21T10:05:56.807Z",
                    "expires_at": -1,
                    "id": 68,
                    "name": "robot@proxy-robot",
                    "secret": "slPnm8Zkp0OGBLec6tTcPuPITgOU2PAn"
                },
                "msg": "OK (144 bytes)",
                "x_envoy_upstream_service_time": "15",
                "x_request_id": "93478b05-897b-4df9-abb4-e07e03723af0"
            }
```

If i add more than one variable

```
project_namespaces:
  - projectName: helm
    Namespaces: 
      - default
      - core
  - projectName: proxy
    Namespaces: 
      - default
      - core
```

based on the variables the expected output should be looks :

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=helm) => {
    "msg": "name: helm, namespace: default, password: Q8mjthgRJFmscjfmqW1QzXEyKjmLEPQm, username: robot@helm-robot"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=helm) => {
    "msg": "name: helm, namespace: core, password: Q8mjthgRJFmscjfmqW1QzXEyKjmLEPQm, username: robot@helm-robot"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=proxy) => {
    "msg": "name: proxy, namespace: default, password: slPnm8Zkp0OGBLec6tTcPuPITgOU2PAn, username: robot@proxy-robot"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=proxy) => {
    "msg": "name: proxy, namespace: core, password: slPnm8Zkp0OGBLec6tTcPuPITgOU2PAn, username: robot@proxy-robot"
}
```

Comment: could you show the content of robot_result?

Comment: @Frenchy, i posted the results in the body. please have a look

Comment: and it is failing when i tried to add more variables

Comment: sorry there is no logic between your first sample output and second sample ouput..in your first sample, the secret is linked to the namespace and for second sample the secret is linked to the project name..

Comment: @Frenchy, i was created another question based on your answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71567971/create-k8s-secrets-by-using-nested-ansible-loops
FYI

Comment: please dont forget to close your question by validating the answer

Answer (score 1):

without knowing the exact content of your result, you could try that:

```
- name: Reproduce issue
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    project_namespaces:
      - projectName: helm
        Namespaces: 
          - default
          - core
    robot_result:
      results:
          - json:
              creation_time: '2022-03-21T10:29:18.331Z'
              expires_at: -1
              id: 75
              username: robot@helm-robot
              secret: YzDDEtJcqYoBL2soZHfTqZxvhIfGKURT
          - json:
              creation_time: '2022-03-21T10:29:22.129Z'
              expires_at: -1
              id: 76
              username: robot@proxy-robot
              secret: 7imXCVAGHV91AkeN7LAhWxQHabmYDRmg

  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "name: {{ item.0.projectName }}, namespace: {{ item.1 }}, password: {{ project.secret }}, username: {{ project.username }}"  #{{ ansible_loop.index0 }}"
      vars:
        project: "{{ (robot_result.results | json_query('[*].json'))[ansible_loop.index0] }}"         
      loop: "{{ project_namespaces | subelements('Namespaces') }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: yes
        label: "{{ item.0.projectName }}"
```

**result:**

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=helm) => {
    "msg": "name: helm, namespace: default, password: YzDDEtJcqYoBL2soZHfTqZxvhIfGKURT, username: robot@helm-robot"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=helm) => {
    "msg": "name: helm, namespace: core, password: 7imXCVAGHV91AkeN7LAhWxQHabmYDRmg, username: robot@proxy-robot"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Frenchy, but when i added more than one variable i was getting error. the details i posted in above body.

Comment: Ils normal your task fails  my answer  is for your  original  question and  you didnt  say  that var could be changed

Comment: So what is your  result  wanted in this case?

Comment: i am sorry for the confusion, i posted the expected output looks like in the above question. for this scenario how could i move on