# create k8s secrets by using nested ansible loops

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create k8s secrets with the storing username and secret in results module of ansible but i created one loop for the name and namespace section and i am trying to create one more loop from the json results output. but it was taking one secret for all the projects

**variables:**

```
project_namespaces:
  - projectName: helm
    Namespaces: 
      - default
      - core
  - projectName: proxy
    Namespaces: 
      - default
      - core
```

**robot_result:**

```
ok: [harbor_stg1_dkp1] => {
    "robot_result": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "content_type": "application/json",
                "cookies": {
                    "sid": "557b377ba2bbe3f054d68bd56b0e10ef"
                },
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "attributes": null,
                        "body": {
                            "description": "pull artifacts for helm",
                            "disable": true,
                            "duration": -1,
                            "level": "system",
                            "name": "helm-robot",
                            "permissions": [
                                {
                                    "access": [
                                        {
                                            "action": "pull",
                                            "resource": "repository"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "kind": "project",
                                    "namespace": "helm"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "body_format": "json",
                        "headers": {
                            "Accept": "application/json",
                            "Authorization": "Basic ",
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        },
                        "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
                        "status_code": [
                            201
                        ],
                        "timeout": 30,
                        "unix_socket": null,
                        "validate_certs": false
                    }
                },
                "item": {
                    "name": "helm-robot",
                    "projectName": "helm"
                },
                "json": {
                    "creation_time": "2022-03-21T10:05:49.248Z",
                    "expires_at": -1,
                    "id": 67,
                    "name": "robot@helm-robot",
                    "secret": "Q8mjthgRJFmscjfmqW1QzXEyKjmLEPQm"
                },
                "x_envoy_upstream_service_time": "18",
                "x_request_id": "496faaa6-bdc4-4e83-890a-2c577576f16b"
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "content_type": "application/json",
                "cookies": {
                    "sid": "6275d7bfe74e71db0a3947f4beb1e159"
                },
                "cookies_string": "sid=6275d7bfe74e71db0a3947f4beb1e159",
                "date": "Mon, 21 Mar 2022 10:05:56 GMT",
                "elapsed": 1,
                "failed": false,
                "failed_when_result": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "attributes": null,
                        "body": {
                            "description": "pull artifacts for proxy",
                            "disable": true,
                            "duration": -1,
                            "level": "system",
                            "name": "proxy-robot",
                            "permissions": [
                                {
                                    "access": [
                                        {
                                            "action": "pull",
                                            "resource": "repository"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "kind": "project",
                                    "namespace": "proxy"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "body_format": "json",
                        "group": null,
                        "headers": {
                            "Accept": "application/json",
                            "Authorization": "Basic ",
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        },
                        "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
                        "method": "POST"
                        ],
                        "timeout": 30,
                        "unix_socket": null,
                        "validate_certs": false
                    }
                },
                "item": {
                    "name": "proxy-robot",
                    "projectName": "proxy"
                },
                "json": {
                    "creation_time": "2022-03-21T10:05:56.807Z",
                    "expires_at": -1,
                    "id": 68,
                    "name": "robot@proxy-robot",
                    "secret": "slPnm8Zkp0OGBLec6tTcPuPITgOU2PAn"
                },
                "msg": "OK (144 bytes)",
                "x_envoy_upstream_service_time": "15",
                "x_request_id": "93478b05-897b-4df9-abb4-e07e03723af0"
            }
```

**task.yaml**

```
- name: Create secrets
  k8s: 
    state: present
    definition:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Secret
      metadata:
        name: "{{ item.0.projectName }}"
        namespace: "{{ item.1 }}"
      stringData:
        password: "{{ project.secret }}"
        username: "{{ project.name }}"
      type: Opaque
  vars:
    project: "{{ (robot_result.results | json_query('[*].json'))[ansible_loop.index0] }}"
  loop: "{{ project_namespaces | subelements('Namespaces') }}"
  loop_control:
    extended: yes
    label: "{{ item.0.projectName }}"
```

when i executing this task i was getting the output like

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=helm) => {
    "msg": "name: helm, namespace: default, password: Q8mjthgRJFmscjfmqW1QzXEyKjmLEPQm, username: robot@helm-robot"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=helm) => {
    "msg": "name: helm, namespace: core, password: slPnm8Zkp0OGBLec6tTcPuPITgOU2PAn, username: robot@proxy-robot"
}
fatal: [harbor_shiplab_stg1_dkp1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: {{ (robot_result.results | json_query('[*].json'))[ansible_loop.index0] }}: list object has no element 2\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ubuntu/konvoy/ansible/roles/harbor-gc/tasks/main.yml': line 47, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Create secrets\n  ^ here\n"}
```

but my requirement would be like this

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=helm) => {
    "msg": "name: helm, namespace: default, password: Q8mjthgRJFmscjfmqW1QzXEyKjmLEPQm, username: robot@helm-robot"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=helm) => {
    "msg": "name: helm, namespace: core, password: Q8mjthgRJFmscjfmqW1QzXEyKjmLEPQm, username: robot@helm-robot"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=proxy) => {
    "msg": "name: proxy, namespace: default, password: slPnm8Zkp0OGBLec6tTcPuPITgOU2PAn, username: robot@proxy-robot"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=proxy) => {
    "msg": "name: proxy, namespace: core, password: slPnm8Zkp0OGBLec6tTcPuPITgOU2PAn, username: robot@proxy-robot"
}
```

As i am new to this ansible i was not much understanding this loops.Any help or suggestions would be appreciated and Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to link secret with projectName:

```
- name: link projectname and json
  set_fact: 
    dico: "{{ dico | d({}) | combine({item.projectName: project[ansible_loop.index0]}) }}"
  vars:
    project: "{{ (robot_result.results | json_query('[*].json')) }}" 
    it: "{{ (robot_result.results | json_query('[*].item')) }}"
  loop: "{{ it }}" 
  loop_control:
    extended: yes

- debug: 
    msg: "name: {{ item.0.projectName }}, namespace: {{ item.1 }}, password: {{ dico[item.0.projectName].secret }}, username: {{ dico[item.0.projectName].username }}"  #{{ ansible_loop.index0 }}"
  vars:
    project: "{{ (robot_result.results | json_query('[*].json')) }}"         
  loop: "{{ project_namespaces | subelements('Namespaces') }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.0.projectName }}"
```

**result:**

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=helm) => {
    "msg": "name: helm, namespace: default, password: YzDDEtJcqYoBL2soZHfTqZxvhIfGKURT, username: robot@helm-robot"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=helm) => {
    "msg": "name: helm, namespace: core, password: YzDDEtJcqYoBL2soZHfTqZxvhIfGKURT, username: robot@helm-robot"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=proxy) => {
    "msg": "name: proxy, namespace: default, password: 7imXCVAGHV91AkeN7LAhWxQHabmYDRmg, username: robot@proxy-robot"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=proxy) => {
    "msg": "name: proxy, namespace: core, password: 7imXCVAGHV91AkeN7LAhWxQHabmYDRmg, username: robot@proxy-robot"
}
```

Comment: glad to help you dont firget to close your twice questions by validating the answer..